# string multiplication using a big integer class

Tags: java, string, multiplication

I'm trying to write a code that multiplies two strings of integers. I'm not too sure where it's going wrong... It works for some numbers, but is horribly wrong for others. I'm not asking for a full solution, but just a hint (I seriously appreciate any help possible) as to where I'm making the obviously silly mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a big integer. ");
    String t = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("And another. ");
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    BigInt a = new BigInt(t);
    BigInt b = new BigInt(s);

    System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + a.add(b));
    System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + a.sub(b));
    System.out.println(a + " * " + b + " = " + a.mul(b));
    System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + a.div(b));
}
}

class BigInt {

public BigInt() {

    n = new int[1];
}

public BigInt(String s) {

    n = new int[s.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
        n[n.length - i - 1] = s.charAt(i) - '0' ;
    }



}

private BigInt(int[] n) {

    this.n = new int[n.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
        this.n[i] = n[i];
    }
}

public String toString() {

    String s = "";

    for (int i : n) {
        s = i + s;
    }

    return s;
}

public BigInt mul(BigInt o) {

        int carry = 0;
        int s = 0;
        int digit;
        int subtotal = 0;
        int total = 0;

        int max = n.length > o.n.length ? n.length : o.n.length;
        int[] result = new int[n.length + o.n.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < o.n.length; ++i) {

        int bottom = i <= o.n.length ? o.n[i] : 0;

        for (s = 0; s <= n.length; ++s){

          int top = s < n.length ? n[s] : 0;
          int prod = (top * bottom + carry);

          if (s == (max-1)) {

            total = Integer.valueOf((String.valueOf(prod) + String.valueOf(subtotal)));
            carry = 0;
            digit = 0;
            subtotal = 0;
            break;
          }

          if (prod < 10) {

            digit = prod;
            subtotal += digit;
            carry = 0;
          }

          if (prod >= 10); {

            digit = prod % 10;
            carry = prod / 10;
            subtotal += digit;
          }
        }
        result[i] = total;
      }
    return new BigInt(trim(result));
}

private int[] trim(int[] nums) {

    int size = nums.length;

    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        if (nums[i] != 0) {
            break;
        }
        --size;
    }

    int[] res = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        res[i] = nums[i];
    }

    return res;
}

private int[] n;
}
```

Comment: what's the error, what are the inputs that are causing the error?

Comment: The product usually ends up being wrong by orders of magnitude, for example 100 * 8 gives 80. It also gives answers like 302 * 51 = 15234.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: He wants us to debug his code

Comment: For a start, don't use Strings in your calculations. You are not clearing the `carry` when the `prod < 10` If it was 1 for example, it will stay 1.  I suggest you step through your code in your debugger with the simplest example you can find where it goes wrong.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah, totally. Cool... I should put in that effort before posting here. I'm still new and haven't used a debugger before. Now's a good time to start I guess, haha.

Comment: Yes, when you have bugs in your code, you should use a debugger first.  You would be surprised how many new developers avoid doing this when in your IDE it is often the button next to run.  Any new tool is hard to use at first but you should find that using a debugger will let you know the problem faster than using SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test using:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            System.out.println(x + " * " + y + " = " + new BigInt(Integer.toString(x)).mul(new BigInt(Integer.toString(y))));

        }
    }
```

demonstrates that somehow your multiply of `x * y` is actually multiplying by `10x * y`. That should give you a clear hint to the problem.